# Indexed Thread on dataset and list

Tags: dataset, map

I currently have a dataset, and I would like to add a column based on another list.

For example:

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"name" -> "bob"|>, <|"name" -> "joe"|>}];
ages = {1,2};
```

I want to get

```
Dataset[{<|"name" -> "bob", "age"->1|>, <|"name" -> "joe", "age"->2|>}];
```

I was thinking of using MapIndex, but I don't really know how to make reform the results into a dataset again, and it seems wasteful.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ds[MapIndexed[Append[#1, "age" -> ages[[First@#2]]] &]]
```

> ```
> {<|"name" -> "bob", "age" -> 1|>, <|"name" -> "joe", "age" -> 2|>}
> ```

Note 10.0.2 throws a warning - who knows what's going on in that private type system:

> ```
>  First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in \
> First[TypeSystem`ZSignatures`PackagePrivate`i]
> ```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how this works? What is the `First` function doing (I understand the rest)

Comment: `MapIndexed` works on multidimensional arrays. `MapIndexed[f, ages]` gives `{f[1, {1}], f[2, {2}]}`. If `ages` were, say, a 2-dim array, then the indexes would be `{i,j}`. In this problem, `First` picks out the rows of `ages`.

Comment: ah, got it. Thank you.

Comment: +1 We can dodge the warning message in 10.0.2 using something like `ds[MapThread[Append[#, "age" -> #2 ] &, {#, ages}] &]`.  Messages like this are due to some serious evaluation leaks in the 10.0.2 type system code :(

Comment: Are you a beta tester for 10.0.3 or is that a typo?

Comment: @WReach What is an "evaluation leak"?

Comment: @soandos An evaluation leak is a type of bug where a function evaluates an expression that should remain unevaluated.  In the current example, the expression `First@#2` is part of a function body and should not be evaluated until that function is called.  Unfortunately, the type system accidentally evaluates that expression prematurely while trying to identify the type of the expression.  This causes the message we see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks, edited. 10.0.3 will be the release that fixes `Dataset` and also casts all the world's data to WDF.

Comment: @WReach, that's a troublesome design, though to be fair, if the power of `Dataset` is like that of a new language interface is probably worth the tradeoff vs openness & breaking EIAE = Everything Is An Expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Dataset@MapThread[
  Append, {Normal[ds], Association["age" -> #] & /@ ages}]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Have fun!